# Some Metro (Universal) apps freeze on lost focus?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, modern-ui

I don't know if it's possible to fix this, but I'd love to know;
I've found that a few of the universal apps, (candy crush is an example) freeze when they lose focus. I was wondering if its possible to change that

I remember the Instagram app did that at one point in the past and it was quite frustrating given I was trying to watch a livestream, it would just stop playing when it went unfocused.

Comment: This is typically an implementation at the software level.  Even a traditional desktop application could exhibit this behavior depending on how it was programmed.  If the applications freeze while they don't have focus, then there isn't much you can do, that is how they were programmed to function.

Comment: ah unfortunate
i've never seen any normal type of application to do this bar some games so i thought it was a metro specific issue

Comment: do you run in tablet mode? here the apps get suspended when you switch away like in Windows 8(.1). Apps must support background tasks to still be able to do works (like downloading, playing audio)

Comment: Yeah I guess its just meant for tablet which doesnt support multi window, hence the freeze when lost focus

Comment: the app lifecycle is explained here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Store apps have a more complex lifecycle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) than Win32 applications:

> Before Windows 8, apps had a simple lifecycle. **Win32 and .NET apps are
>   either running or not running. When a user minimizes them, or switches
>   away from them, they continue to run.** This was fine until portable
>   devices and power management became increasingly important.
>
> Windows 8 introduced a new application model with UWP apps. At a high
>   level, a new suspended state was added. **A UWP app is suspended
>   shortly after the user minimizes it or switches to another app. This
>   means that the app's threads are stopped and the app is left in memory
>   unless the operating system needs to reclaim resources. When the user
>   switches back to the app, it can be quickly restored to a running
>   state.**
>   By default, apps that are not in the foreground are suspended which
>   results in power savings and more resources available for the app
>   currently in the foreground.
>
> The suspended state adds new requirements for you as a developer
>   because the operating system may elect to terminate a suspended app in
>   order to free up resources. The terminated app will still appear in
>   the task bar. When the user click on it, the app must restore the
>   state that it was in before it was terminated because the user will
>   not be aware that the system closed the app. They will think that it
>   has been waiting in the background while they were doing other things
>   and will expect it to be in the same state it was in when they left
>   it. In this topic we will look at how to accomplish that.

[image]

To continue doing work, the apps must support background tasks:

> There are various ways for apps that need to continue to run when they
>   are in the background such as **background tasks, extended execution,
>   and activity sponsored execution (for example, the
>   BackgroundMediaEnabled capability which allows an app to continue to
>   play media in the background)**. Also, background transfer operations
>   can continue even if your app is suspended or even terminated.

So the apps you use don't support this and get suspended as expected.

In the Windows SDK, there is a [tool to disable the lifecycle for an app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19459956/1466046)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\plmdebug.exe" /enableDebug <PackageFullName>
```

Do this for the apps you want to continue.